# ifconfig not showing all IPs bound to the machine

Tags: networking, server

I have configured multiple IP addresses on a ubuntu box, but when I run `ifconfig` it shows just one of them. I am able, however, to ping all other adresses assigned to this machine.

`/etc/network/interface` contents:

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
     address 192.168.202.11
     netmask 255.255.255.0
     network 192.168.202.0
     broadcast 192.168.202.255
     gateway 192.168.202.1

# dns-* options are implemented by the resolvconf package, if installed   
dns-search idil.dz1.da

auto eth0:1    
iface eth0:1 inet static
     address 192.168.202.12   
     netmask 255.255.255.0

auto eth0:2
iface eth0:2 inet static
     address 192.168.202.13
     netmask 255.255.255.0

auto eth0:3
iface eth0:3 inet static
     address 192.168.202.14
     netmask 255.255.255.0

auto eth0:4
iface eth0:4 inet static
     address 192.168.202.15
     netmask 255.255.255.0

auto eth0:5
iface eth0:5 inet static
     address 192.168.202.16   
     netmask 255.255.255.0
```

However, the output of the `ifconfig` is only:

`192.168.202.11`

Comment: ifconfig -a display everything?

Comment: it is showing only eth0 ip address..:(

Comment: Which Ubuntu release are you running?  Please add your information to bug #921280 too.

Comment: `ip addr show` works

Answer (score 27):

`ifconfig` is essentially deprecated, although there are no plans that I am aware of to get rid of it. The replacement is the `ip` command. The modern equivalent of `ifconfig` on its own is `ip address list`.

Why has `ifconfig` been replaced with `ip`? Much new functionality has been added to Linux networking in the decades since `ifconfig` was written. This involved an entirely new API (netlink) for the userspace tool to speak to the kernel to configure the network. It was far more practical to write a new tool to better map the new functionality through the netlink API and down to the command line, than to try and adapt the old `ifconfig` tool. Check out the [ip(8) manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/raring/en/man8/ip.8.html) for all the cool new stuff that you can do now.

The kernel API used by `ifconfig` and the `ifconfig` tool itself remains for backwards compatibility, but this interface is blind to anything that does not easily map to the old model.

The reason that `ifconfig` doesn't show you the IP aliases is that it looks like they are being added by Debian's `ifupdown` (the package that handles `/etc/network/interfaces`) using a different mechanism that does not add the labels `:1`, `:2`, etc. So the `ifconfig` tool is blind to them, since the old API mandated these labels, and so the extra addresses do not map to the old API. From the [ip-address(8) manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/raring/en/man8/ip-address.8.html):

```
          Each address may be tagged with a label string.  In order to
          preserve compatibility with Linux-2.0 net aliases, this string
          must coincide with the name of the device or must be prefixed
          with the device name followed by colon.
```

The bugs linked in maggotbrain's answer seem to be focused around adding support to `ifconfig` to read addresses without labels. Another approach might be to arrange for `ifupdown` to create the addresses with labels, such that `ifconfig` will be able to see them without modification.

Comment: Thanks for the info!  A little hint on the ifconfig usage would have been nice for plebs like I who only use Linux as a tool.  They could have made ifconfig call IP with ifconfig parameter equivalents to not disrupt plebs such as I.  Sigh.

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely a bug in the net-tools package and `ifconfig` specifically.

See the launchpad bugs [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/net-tools/+bug/921280) and [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/net-tools/+bug/693230) for additional information.

If you enter your interfaces manually, from the command line using `ifconfig` like this(following your above configuration):

```
sudo ifconfig eth0:1 192.168.202.12 netmask 255.255.255.0
sudo ifconfig eth0:2 192.168.202.13 netmask 255.255.255.0
sudo ifconfig eth0:3 192.168.202.14 netmask 255.255.255.0
sudo ifconfig eth0:4 192.168.202.15 netmask 255.255.255.0
sudo ifconfig eth0:5 192.168.202.16 netmask 255.255.255.0
```

You will have those interfaces show up, as expected, when running `ifconfig`.

These changes will not show up in your `/etc/network/interfaces`, however. 
So, you will need to add them in both places.

**Note: This is also not persistent across interface resets, so you will need to re-run the commands upon restarting the interface/machine.**